# ng-view doesn't show in index html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My goal is doing routing page on web app.
I have writted 2 pages: index and home.
In index page, there is ng-view which is calling home page.
But browser doesn't show any home page.
Maybe I'm mistake to write script.js...

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="productsCtrl">
        <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>            
            <div id="main">

                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div ng-view> 
                </div>

            </div>
        </body>
```

scripts.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/home.html'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);
```

Someone can help men about this. Thanks

Comment: `ng-app` directive is missing, or you manually bootstraping Angular?

Comment: I wrote ng-app in <html ng-app="myApp">

Answer (score -1):

You have to use ng-app directive

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: This would cause exception. In my opinion Angular does not even start because of missing  `ng-app` directive or bootstraping code.

Comment: Yup pretty much what we are all saying ^_^

Comment: I also noticed he has "'header.html'" :o double quotes and single. Wouldn't that cause the header.html not to load?

Comment: Everything is working. But templateUrl is something error. Because of I have tried to put in scripts.js: template: "<strong>Working?<strong>" then home page showed one line: "Working?". In the case, templateUrl: [my folder].... not working.

Comment: If templateUrl is not working for you then that would be because of your path. Try it as 
templateUrl: './templates/home.html' with a single dot instead of double.

Also from your browser make sure that templates/home.html is accessible.